# What's the meaning of "etch out"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I came across this sentence on [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_the_main): (from the entry **in the main**)

> ‘It was a victory etched out in the main through a team effort and a very fine one at that.’

I can't seem to find "etch out" defined anywhere as a phrasal verb. Can a victory be "etched out"?

Comment: It's not an expression I've heard as it is used there, "to accomplish something with assiduous effort", but it does seem analogous to **carve out** which is also used in a similar way.  *The settlers carved out a life for themselves in the unforgiving climate.*

Comment: I would have expected **eked out** there, assuming it was a hard-fought struggle for the entire team, won by a narrow margin.   ("to get with great effort", according to [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eke%20out).)

Answer (score 1):

They are indicating that it was a victory that was only won through **Hard work** that if the team didn't work as hard as they did it may not have turned out so well. Imagine sculpting a sculpture as the goal, the team had to **etch out** their victory to be successful.